# Lyx Cross referencing shows label instead of figure number for <reference> on page <page> format

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

Hi I'm currently writing my thesis,

I have separated my chapters out into individual lyx documents and includes them into a main lyx document

As I render, I get 
seen in Figure ??fig:Modified-Ludzack-ettinger on the following page.

instead of

seen in Figure 2.1 on the following page.

If i switch the cross referencing format to just reference (without page) it renders correctly.

Anyone has any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  References are first displayed correctly in the output after the second run of latex (the renderer).  If that is not the case, then you will need to show us some details of your document and set-up.  See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4488/15925 giving advice on how to present that here.

Comment: I ended up referencing the figure twice, once for the figure number and second time for the page which gives me the same result